# In which of the following cases is it true that $\mathbb{R}^4=U\oplus V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Background**

I am working on my linear algebra homework for the week and I have hit a wall with the first problem.  I am not the best with this material so answer like I have no clue what I'm doing if you can.  The book used in the course is *Abstract Linear Algebra* by Curtis.

---

**The Problem**

Suppose that $x,y,u$ and $v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$; let $U,V$ be vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $\{x,y\}$ and $\{u,v\}$ respectively. In which of the following cases is it true that $\mathbb{R}^4=U\oplus V$.

(a) $x=(1,1,0,0), y=(1,0,1,0), u=(0,1,0,1), v=(0,0,1,1)$

(b) $x=(-1,1,1,0), y=(0,1,-1,1), u=(1,0,0,0), v=(0,0,0,1)$

(c) $x=(1,0,0,1), y=(0,1,1,0), u=(1,0,1,0), v=(0,1,0,1)$

---

**Attempt at a Solution for (a)**

Here we see that span$(U)=\{(1,1,0,0),(1,0,1,0)\}$ and span$(V)=\{(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,1)\}$.

Thus any vector $u'\in U$ can be written as a linear combination of $x$ and $y$, i.e. for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $u'=a(1,1,0,0)+b(1,0,1,0)=(a,a,0,0)+(b,0,b,0)=(a+b,a,b,0)$.

Similarly, any vector $v'\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$, i.e. for $c,d\in \mathbb{R}$, $v'=c(0,1,0,1)+d(0,0,1,1)=(0,c,0,c)+(0,0,d,d)=(0,c,d,c+d)$.  Recall that the external direct sum of a vector space $V$ and a vector space $U$ is defined as $$U\oplus V=\{(u,v)| u\in U,v\in V\}.$$  Thus in this case $$U\oplus V=\{(a+b,a,b, 0),(0,c,d,c+d)| a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

---

**Confusion**

First off, I am not certain if anything I actually said in my attempt at a solution was correct in the slightest.  Secondly, if it even is correct, I cannot tell if I am on the right track.  How do we show that $\mathbb{R}^4=U\oplus V$?  Is showing that the same as showing that the span of $U\oplus V$ generates $\mathbb{R^4}$?

As always, any advice would be immensely appreciated!  Thank you all in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the definition, $\Bbb R^4 = U \oplus V$ if $U \cap V=0$ and $\Bbb R^4 = U+ V.$

Now lets check wach option:

a) $x=(1,1,0,0), y=(1,0,1,0), u=(0,1,0,1), v=(0,0,1,1)$

We can see that stuff in $U$ is of the form $a(1,1,0,0)+b(1,0,1,0)=(a+b,a,b,0)$
and stuff in $V$ is of the form $c(0,1,0,1)+d(0,0,1,1)=(0,c,d,c+d)$ it's easy to note that $U \cap V=\{(0,0,0,0)\}$.

Now let's check $\Bbb R^4 = U+ V$, for this is enough to show that $\Bbb R^4 = span\{x,y,u,v\}$ and this is proven by seeing that $\{x,y,u,v\}$ is a linearly independent set of 4 elements and thus it's a basis for $\Bbb R^4$.

b) $ x=(−1,1,1,0),y=(0,1,−1,1),u=(1,0,0,0),v=(0,0,0,1)$

Stuff in $U$ is of the form $a(-1,1,1,0)+b(0,1,-1,1)=(-a,a+b,a-b,b)$ and stuff in $V$ is of the form $c(1,0,0,0)+d(0,0,0,1)=(c,0,0,d)$.
Here again noting that you can't have a affect the second an third entries with elements in $V$ and noting that elements in $U$ have non zero second and third entries you can see $U \cap V=\{(0,0,0,0)\}$.

Again, let's check $\Bbb R^4 = U+ V$, for this is enough to show that $\Bbb R^4 = span\{x,y,u,v\}$ and this is proven by seeing that $\{x,y,u,v\}$ is a linearly independent set of 4 elements and thus it's a basis for $\Bbb R^4$.

c) x=(1,0,0,1),y=(0,1,1,0),u=(1,0,1,0),v=(0,1,0,1)

Stuff in $U$ is of the form $a(1,0,0,1)+b(0,1,1,0)=(a,b,b,a)$ and stuff in $V$ is of the form $c(1,0,1,0)+d(0,1,0,1)=(c,d,c,d)$.
Here note that $(1,1,1,1)$ is both in $U$ and in $V$ so $U \cap V$ is not equal to $\{(0,0,0,0)\}$ and $\Bbb R^4$ can't be equal to $ U \oplus V$.

Hope it helps. 
You can check the linear independence using row elimination or any method you like, also the fact that you have 4 linearly independent vectors and that $dim(\Bbb R^4)=4$ is what assures that the set is a basis and it spans $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it all in layman's terms for me.  It makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

**Proof:** Observe that for subspaces we have that $\dim(V\oplus U)\leq\dim(U)+\dim(V)$ and equality precisely when $V\cap U=\{0\}$. If you want to prove this, it's immediate from Rank-Nullity or can be proven pretty quickly from first principles. From the premise of the problem, we know that $\dim(U)\leq 2$ and $\dim(V)\leq 2$. Therefore the only way that they can give all of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is if both $U$ and $V$ have dimension $2$ and intersection $\{0\}$. This happens precisely when all four vectors are linearly independent.

---

What you've written is wrong, primarily because you incorrectly transcribed $y$. The correct value of $y$ gives $u'=(a+b,a,b,0)$, instead of $(a+b,a+b,0,0)$ as you have written.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Stella.  So correct me if I'm wrong, but does this mean that $\dim(\mathbb{R}^4)=4$?  Or is that even a thing?  I'm sorry, I'm just very poor with this material and I'm frustrating to help, so I appreciate it.

Comment: @ThyArtisMath $\dim(\mathbb{R}^4)=4$, yes. $F^k$ always has dimension $k$. That's a significant part of why we notate it like that. $\mathbb{R}^4$ is the unique vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $4$. I've also edited my answer to mention the error you've made in your computation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance here.  It makes alot more sense now.